# How to use CognitoIdentityCredentials when importing only required clients?

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

As `aws-sdk` is huge to use at browser side, and also that I'm using Webpack, so it made more sense to only include clients which I'm using (like `import S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3'`). However I'm failing to configure the credentials for clients like here I am able to do in my `AWS` import:

```js
AWS.config.update({
  region: '<a-region>',
  credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: '<an-identifier>',
  }),
});
```

In `aws-sdk`, while type (of TypeScript) shows that `CognitoIdentityCredentials` is directly exportable from `aws-sdk/lib/credentials/cognito_identity_credentials`, it actually isn't. I'm unable to find another way to import `CognitoIdentityCredentials` directly in my project.